What is the default redirect uri for Google Sign-In on Android?
Google discourages using a custom redirect url for security reasons. Thus, if you don't enable custom redirect urls, there's presumably a correct default redirect url, and any other redirect url leads to a "Custom URI scheme is not enabled for your Android client" error during the login flow. However, I can't find any hints from Google as to what redirect url /is/ correct, and nothing I've tried works. When I check "Enable custom URI scheme" in the Cloud Console, my login works, so I know the issue isn't something else, and I'm just not picking the right redirect url.
What redirect url does Google want you to use?
On iOS, Google actually gives direction: it says to use com.googleusercontent.apps.CLIENT_ID. (This seems like imprecise advice, as you need to give a path as well to make it work, e.g. com.googleusercontent.apps.CLIENT_ID:/oauth2redirect/google). On Android, I've tried tons of variations of com.googleusercontent.apps.CLIENT_ID:/oauth2redirect/google and PACKAGE_NAME:/oauth2redirect/google, but nothing works (short of just disabling this security restriction)

Are you trying to login via WebView in an Android/iOS app? If so, that doesn't work anymore and you're going to have to implement the Google sign in SDK in your apps.

I'm using the AppAuth oauth library that appears to send the user to a new activity rather than using a WebView. It works perfectly when I check the box for "Use a custom URI scheme", so I don't thiiink WebViews are the problem.
